# Is it okay to change variables here? What is the proper justification?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\phi(x),y) dy\right|^p dx$$ is finite and that $\phi$ is monotone and differentiable almost everywhere. Can one change variables $\phi(x)=\xi$ ?

If $f(x,.)$ is an $L^1$ function then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\phi(x),y) dy$ is continuous almost everywhere (because $\phi$ is continuous almost everywhere).
Does the existence of the integral imply that $f(x,.)$ is necessarily $L^1$? And what then ?

Comment: Apologies for deleting my earlier question.  I realised it wasn't enough to clear up what I was confused about.  When you ask  "Does the existence of the integral imply that $f$ is necessarily $L^p$ in the second variable?" are you asking whether $\ \int_\limits{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(\phi(x),y)|^pdydx<\infty\ $?

Comment: Okay. I see your point. let me edit a bit. Actually the question was pretty messed up. Sorry for that.